# Email Notification For FDS Filter

Tags: authorize.net

I am using authorize.net for transaction processing.I have enable amount & transaction velocity filter in FDS(Fraud Detection Suite) for fraud prevention and also I have set action to decline the transaction when these filters are triggered. I am doing transactions to trigger these FDS filters. Filters are triggered & transactions also declined but I was not received any kind of email notification for these FDS filter triggering.

Kindly help .

Thanks
Amol

Answer (score 0):

You can login to your Authorize.Net interface to configure this by going to Tools, click on Fraud Detection Suite on your left hand side, under General on your left column you will see a link for "Email Notifications".  You can opt to receive an email notification each time an enabled filter is triggered by a transaction and add the email address in that page.